# Time needed to charge capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, capacitance

In the given circuit, the capacitor of capacitance $C$ is charged by closing key $K$ at $t = 0$. Find the time required to charge the capacitor upto maximum charge for the given circuit, if it were to be charged with the constant initial charging rate at $t = 0$ in the given circuit.

[image]

I have to find the time as a value of $xRC$ where $x$ is a fraction. I do not know if the time constant will have equivalent circuit resistance or just the resistance in series with the capacitor. Also i used $$q=q_0(1-e^{-t/(RC)}).$$ Using this I get zero on one side after taking $\log$. This is from a reference book and there isn't a solution provided. Please help me out.

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Commenters, please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Comment: I totally agree with this but now you've closed the question and my query still isn't resolved as I hadn't seen those comments. Please open it so that someone can answer it.